# Set default link for iOS webapp

Tags: ios, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm playing around with iOS' [webapps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

I'd like to configure the webapp to save to the user's home screen with a **different url** from the original web page.

On Android, you can change "start_url" in the manifest.json to achieve this.

The various customisation options on iOS seem to be less well documented. But I'm hoping there's a meta tag I can use, similar to this one that changes the web app title:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="[your title]" />
```

which is documented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546037/set-default-ios-web-clip-icon-title).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the url for the "Add to home screen" on iPhone Safari be customized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887676/can-the-url-for-the-add-to-home-screen-on-iphone-safari-be-customized)

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 11.3, Safari now supports web app manifests, making it possible to specify the start URL. Learn more [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/).